# Restify and Angular CORS No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: javascript, cors, restify

I faced with that problem when implementing REST api with Restify secured with bearer token authorization type.

when I sending simple get request to API server it fails with CORS problem

> 405 (Method Not Allowed) angular.js:7962
>
> OPTIONS http://api.host.com/tests No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is
>   present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://local.host.com' is
>   therefore not allowed access.

---

Solution described in my answer, so it's not real question for me, because I placed it when already know the answer, but hope it will save time for someone else in future.

Comment: It says the page is not set up to make CORs requests. Did you set it up?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The problem was faced because of restify has internal CORS module who manage CORS logic. in this module you could find list of allowed headers, by default it's

```
[
        'accept',
        'accept-version',
        'content-type',
        'request-id',
        'origin',
        'x-api-version',
        'x-request-id'
]
```

As I say in the question, I use bearer token auth, so I send my request with `Authorization` header. It's not included in default list, and that's why my request fails.

To fix that problem we need to add this header to the list of ALLOW_HEADERS. for that in my restify configuration code I add this line:

```
restify.CORS.ALLOW_HEADERS.push('authorization');
```

Think that info could be helpfull if you faced with similar problem, because I spend a lot to find the solution.

Comment: After the push `restify.CORS.ALLOW_HEADERS.push('Access-Control-Allow-Origin');` be sure to `server.use(restify.CORS());`

Comment: Hey Ph0en1x, many, many thanks! I've the same enviroment: angular + restify + bearer token and some hours trying to find a solution.

Comment: i am using restify 5.0.1, and can't find the solution regarding CORS

Answer (score 6):

You won't be able to access the URL `http://api.host.com/tests` from a file deployed at `http://local.host.com` due to the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

As the source (origin) page and the target URL are at different domains, your code is actually attempting to make a **[Cross-domain (CORS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) request** (thus the error with **`OPTIONS`** -- see the explanation below), not an ordinary `GET`.

In a few words, the same-origin policy enforces that browsers only allow Ajax calls to services in the **same domain** as the HTML page.

**Example:** A page in `http://www.example.com/myPage.html` can only directly request services that are in `http://www.example.com`, like `http://www.example.com/testservice/etc`. If the service is in other domain, the browser won't make the direct call (as you'd expect). Instead, it will try to make a CORS request.

To put it shortly, to perform a CORS request, your browser:

- Will first send an `OPTION` request to the target URL
- And then **only if** the server response to that `OPTIONS` contains the [adequate headers (**`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is one of them**)](http://enable-cors.org/server.html) to allow the CORS request, the browse will perform the call (almost exactly the way it would if the HTML page was at the same domain).

**If the expected headers don't come in the `OPTIONS`, the browser will give up, informing the error (that it attempted a CORS request and didn't find the necessary headers).**

**How to solve it?**

- Place the target service in the same domain of the origin page; or
- Enable CORS (enable the necessary headers) on the server; or
- If you don't have server-side access to the service, you could also mirror it (create a copy of it in the server you own).
- [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) is also a solution if you just want to request information (but this would require server-side access to setup as well).

Comment: it's on the same domain, but different subdomain. But I already find solution myself, just placed it there to save time for someone else in future.

Comment: To the browser, the subdomain is a different domain. Even a different port is a different domain (that is: `example.com:8080` is considered to be a different domain than `example.com:80`).